# Strip all non letters and numbers from a string in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a variable that has a string which recieves strange characters like hearts.

Besides that point, I wanted to know anyhow: How do I leave a string with only letters and numbers, discarding the rest or replacing it with nothing (not adding a space or anything)

My first thought was using a regular expression but I wanted to know if Powershell had something more native that does it automatically.

Comment: If there is no way to do it natively, then I guess a regular expression will have to do, although I perfer to avoid it.

Answer (score 15):

Let say you have variable like this:

```
$temp = '^gdf35#&fhd^^h%(@$!%sdgjhsvkushdv'
```

you can use the -replace method to replace only the Non-word characters like this:

```
$temp -replace "\W"
```

The result will be:

```
gdf35fhdhsdgjhsvkushdv
```

Comment: $temp -replace "\W" will do or does it have to be $temp = $temp -replace "\W" Maybe even both work...Ill try it out.

Comment: if you want to update the $temp variable with the new result then do: $temp = $temp -replace "\W"

Answer (score 5):

Consider white-listing approved characters, and replace anything that isn't whitelisted:

```
$temp = 'This-Is-Example!"£$%^&*.Number(1)'
$temp -replace "[^a-zA-Z0-9]"

ThisIsExampleNumber1
```

This gives added flexibility if you ever do want to include non-alphanumeric characters which may be expected as part of the string (e.g. dot, dash, space).

```
$temp = 'This-is-example!"£$%^&*.Number(2)'
$temp -replace "[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]"

This-is-example.Number2
```

Answer (score 1):

Since all other answers do not consider `_` as a special character, I'd suggest using

```
$temp -replace '[\W_]+'
```

See the [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/WLKDVv/2).

Here, `[\W_]+` matches one or more (`+`) non-word characters (`\W`) or underscores (`_`). The `_` inside the character class is necessary since `\W`, being a `\w` reverse counterpart, does not match a `_` char that is considered a character of a word type. Note that all shorthand character classes in .NET regexes are Unicode-aware, so `[\W_]` matches any non-word (any non-letters or non-digits or non-underscores) and `_` characters (i.e. we put the `_` "back in").

Alternatively, you can also remove all characters other than any letter or number (including any Unicode letters and numbers):

```
$temp -replace '[^\p{L}\p{N}]+'
```

See the [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/WLKDVv/1).